# Ubuntu isn't playing dvd

Tags: 16.04, vlc, dvd, gstreamer

Same DVD is playing in windows, but ubunut(16.04) isn't displaying any media. `/media/` directory is empty. It contains video only.

i had tried these commands but it didn't work.

```
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
sudo apt-get install libdvdcss libdvdread4 libdvdnav4
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-base
sudo apt-get install vlc
sudo regionset /dev/sr0
sudo regionset
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With what program/app are you trying to play the DVD? Or do you just navigate to the folder with Nautilus?

Answer (score -1):

I think that the order of commands is important.  The command to install the libdvd(css/read4/nav4) should have come first, and then the libdvd-pkg install command should have been issued.

The simple thing is to try:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg

Comment: still not working.